# CSS link color style overwrite

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, styles

Im totally angry ! I hope someone can me add a great tip how to fix this problem.

So... I created 2 div and inside these two div is a LINK with different colors. Everything is working fine but when i change the second link color that overwrites my first link... Almost everytime i got this problem...

My css code :

```
.button a, a:link, a:visited { text-decoration:none; font-size:12px; color:#FFF; }
.button a:hover { cursor:pointer; color:#FFF; }

.post-share-comment a, a:link, a:visited { font-size:12px; color:#000; }
.post-share-comment a:hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

My .button link color is white but on the web isn't... On the web is dark... and when i add this post-share-comment div over the .button than my button is white but the other link is white too... so **the second style overwrites the first** ??? Why is this ???

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commas break up complete selectors, not components of them

This:

```
 .post-share-comment a, a:link, a:visited {}
```

Means:

```
 .post-share-comment a {}
 a:link {}
 a:visited {}
```

Not:

```
 .post-share-comment a {}
 .post-share-comment a:link {}
 .post-share-comment a:visited {}
```

Your selector should be:

```
 .post-share-comment a,
 .post-share-comment a:link,
 .post-share-comment a:visited {}
```

If you don't want to write out the full syntax then you can use a preprocess such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which would allow:

```
 .post-share-comment {
     a,
     a:link,
     a:visited {}
 }
```

Comment: OMG! :D This works man ! Thanks a lot. I learned it wrong >_< Cool

Comment: @user1938141  its always a good practice to accept the answer which solved your problem. it helps other to find solution easily when they have same problem